# Using Typescript 2 "noUnusedLocals" with Angular2 or NativeScript

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript, typescript2.0

I'd like to enforce the new `noUnusedLocals` of Typescript 2.0 in my applications but all my functions that are references from the HTML are tagged as "never used" and are marked as errors.

example:

HTML

```
<button ng-click="onButtonClick()">Upload</button>
```

Typescript (inside the Component Class)

```
private onButtonClick(): void      //'onButtonClick' is declared but never used
{
    console.log('onButtonClick');
}
```

Is there a way to either silent these errors for specific functions or reference the HTML file so typescript knows they are used? I would really like to keep this functionality for code maintenance.

Comment: TS is unaware of what A2 does with this method, so no. It is a matter of semantics. `onButtonClick` may be considered public because it is used by a template. It is unlikely that you will have really public methods in component that are supposed to be called from outside of the component by you and not the framework.

Comment: Right, I was being overkill for no good reason, thank you for the reality check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try marking your function as `public` (which it should be) and because the class is exported and the function being public then TS should not complain about it being used.

```
public onButtonClick(): void ...
```

Comment: or no access specifier would also make it public